# How to include my application as a dialing option when calling from the addressbook?

Tags: android

I need to include additional dialing options in the menu appearing after pressing "Call" over a contact ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpOis.png)).

I'm trying to do it with action-filters for the DIAL and CALL intents without any success.

I know this is possible because Skype does it ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpOis.png)).  Anybody knows how to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `Intent` you're looking for is `android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED`. Have a look at the [complete Skype manifest](http://cdn.www-jo.se/f.pfleger/msc/skypemanifest.xml).

Comment: I am confused why you put skype manifest here. But I need to put skype name when dialing from my application. How to do that? Isn't it going to automatically in the dialing list when Skype is installed? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd start here:
[using android dialer in 3rd party app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499550)

And look through the [Android dialer source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/froyo-release/AndroidManifest.xml) to see what intents it uses

Then, check the [official Intent list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

Which leads me to guess you need to at least include:

- VIEW
- DIAL
- CALL

in category **`DEFAULT`**

Comment: +1 for the idea of looking at the source code, although it should be the Contacts application.   I found that the intent is CALL_PRIVILEGED as suggested by Josef: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/com/android/contacts/ContactsUtils.java;hb=HEAD