# Android dialer application

Tags: android, phone-call

I am figuring out a way to replace the default dialer application from my custom dialer application, but I am not getting how to achieve this.

Here is what I want

- Create a custom dialer UI
- My application is called whenever call button hardware or that one in Android is pressed
- The application can also be called from the contact screen

I am referring to [public static final String ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL).

Comment: Here you can find a custom dialer : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/PadLayout

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. Create a simple Android application (our dialer). To actually call someone, you just need that method:

   ```
   private void performDial(String numberString) {
       if (!numberString.equals("")) {
          Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + numberString);
          Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
          startActivity(dial);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Give your application permission to call in AndroidManifest

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
   ```
3. Set in AndroidManifest intention that says to your phone to use your app when need a dialer

When someone press the call button:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When someone fire an URI:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply its really great I got what I want but my app only opens when when I use hardware call button but if I use android softkey for making call its not working

Comment: If your phone ui (ie. htc sense) starts its own dialer instead of fire dialer activity then there's really nothing you could do...

Comment: thanks one more thing when I use dialer first time android asks me to choose between default dialer and my app how can I surpass this so that automatically my dialer is accepted without user interaction

Comment: You can't. At least for my knowledge.

Comment: If you see contacts application code, you will see android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED is used. Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293864/how-to-include-my-application-as-a-dialing-option-when-calling-from-the-addressb

Comment: When dialing from a 3rd-party contacts app, I need to do action.CALL instead of action.DIAL for my app to show up on the list.  Not even this works, however, when calling a number using the default contacts list or recent call list.  If I do CALL_PRIVILEGED, all works (this is what skype does).  The confusing thing for me, though, is that a google blog post highly discourages the use of CALL_PRIVILEGED.  But, I see no other way.  Post here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html

Comment: how do you design the layout. any guide on that ?

Comment: This is not working if you wanted to create own dialler application. This is simply to redirect your call to native/available app. Any idea how to mark your application as dialler application ? CALL_PRIVILEGED seems one thing but that is also not working !! Any suggestion !

Comment: it's not a dialer app, it will use default app to call

Comment: How can I prevent the dialer from prompting my app? I just want incoming calls to be allowed

Comment: Then how to get the number clicked..? I mean when someone click a number from other app, then choose to open with our app, then how to get the number to show on my own app..?

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- open activity when establishing a call -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: As I commented under another answer, this works for me. I think its weird, though, that Google discouraged using this intent in a recent blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html .  If I follow their suggestion by using NEW_OUTGOING_CALL, my app doesn't show up alongside other apps, such as Skype, as an option for calls when making calls from the contacts app.  Also, they claim that CALL_PRIVILEGED is available only for system apps.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856583/1103974) by [arekolek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916449/arekolek).

This is the correct way to extend an InCallService by a third-party app, that will replace the system default dialer and InCallScreen after the user accepts the prompt at startup.

He also provides a [working sample app](https://github.com/arekolek/simple-phone) in Kotlin (bonus points).

Please upvote his answer there, I do not deserve credit for his work.

Note: will only work for API 23+, and might need [extra permissions in API 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS)

Answer (score 2):

The ACTION_DIAL intent appears to allow you to pass a number to call to the standard dialer, ready for the user to call it, if they wish to do so, so isn't what you need.

Do you have a specific question, or are you looking for someone to tell you how to implement your app being called when the software/hardware call button is pressed?

Looks like you need ACTION_CALL_BUTTON - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL_BUTTON

Comment: yeah all I want is create a custom dialer I have used android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON this only but its not working for me

Comment: Saurabh, did you able to resolve the issue? Share the solution so that community can be benefited.

Comment: @ingsaurabh:pl share the answer if you found the solution.

Comment: I was able to overlay a view on top of the native dialer app.For more see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701879/popup-window-on-incoming-call-screen-like-truecaller/24377603#24377603