# Creating own dialer

Tags: android

I want to create my own dialor which will have own widgets for call connecting and disconnecting.How to do it? please help me out as I am beginner tell me in brief.

Thanks!

Comment: Here you can find a custom dialer : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/PadLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was already answered here so you can use that for the [custom dialer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303138/how-to-make-my-own-custom-dialer-in-an-android-phone) part:

as for the widget part, I find google's guide most helpful:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html