# Delaying Incoming Calls Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

A pop up appears in each android cell phone when a call is to be received and then the user accepts or reject the call from on that page . I am looking for a code in android which can delay the time of that pop up . For example when a call is received on the cell phone that pop up waits for 2 to 3 seconds before appearing on screen .

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a custom dialer.

You can find additional information in this past [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170752/creating-own-dialer).

Comment: Even custom dialer takes time to appear and default dialer first appear and after that custom dialer appears . Is there a way i can suppress the incoming call.

Comment: You can't suppress it. it's is an anti-hijacking mechanism.

Comment: Is their anyother way around to this problem ?