# PhoneGap: Make phone call within application

Tags: javascript, cordova

Is there a way to initiate a phone call within an application using PhoneGap?

I know it's possible to use `tel:` hyperlinks to invoke the dialer, but this means that the application is paused. I'm trying to get this to work from within the application.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can make a dialer application inside your application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303138/how-to-make-my-own-custom-dialer-in-an-android-phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CallNumber](https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin) cordova plugin (`call-number` on npm) to make the actual call.

To keep running in the background (when your app is paused due the dialer taking over), there is [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode). As your app will keep running, you can use the success callback passed to the CallNumber API to do stuff when the phone-call has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap/Cordova does not have a JS Function to be able to do what you desire. For Android this requires a special Intent, for iOS it is not possible.

You will need to create a custom Cordova/PhoneGap plugin using this guide. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/

To achieve the same resolution as this related question. [How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)