# Android Dialing Screen Change

Tags: android

As the default screen shows the dialing number like this

[image]

but what i want is that on dialing screen i could change the dialing number.
meanwhile...
dialing no. 9999888877
on dialing screen no. should be 
dialing.... 0116547896
and the no. should ring at 9999888877

means the first image's dialing screen should be replaced with this

[image]
so please help me out...
i only want to change the dialing screen.
not the dialled number.

Comment: So, you want help to hide the actual dialed number from the user? Just out of interest, do you have a premium-rate phone line set up?

Comment: yes,that's what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be able to do this with the default android dialer.

You would have to write your own dialer application.

Comment: Actually i am totally new to android.
So can u please help me by telling that 
1. How to create own dialer.
2. How to make own dialer as a default dialer

Comment: Creating your own dialer means writing an entire dialer app from scratch. It would entail creating a dialer keypad, and hooking into the phone apis.
This link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303138/how-to-make-my-own-custom-dialer-in-an-android-phone - contains some good links.