# Android dial internal phone number

Tags: android, telephony

I want to create an Android application to use my tablet as door opener.

The door opener system is connected to my router and with the internal telefons I´m able to open the door e.g. if I dial the internal number of the door opener system.

Within my app I want to have e.g. a Button. If the button is pressed the internal number of the door opener should be called and so I can open the door.

The second thing would be to speak over the app with the person who rang the bell. So the app should have phone capabilities but I don´t want to use the system own phone dialog. I want to do this within my app.

Which API I have to use? I have installed the app FritzAppFon on my device and with this app I can do telephone calls (external and internal). Cause of this I think it should be possible to create such a app.

Comment: What are you trying to say here ?

Comment: Interesting. May i know what product are you talking about? Is it something you are building yourself or something commercially available?

Comment: Also - this might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/10303212/847575

Comment: i found out, that I can realize this with SIP. I have found a java application which use SIP and I can contact the door opener via SIP call. Now I´m looking for a simple to use SIP API. Which SIP API is good and simple to use? Thanks.