# Is it possible to replace Android's inbuilt Caller with Custom UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, phone-call, receiver, android-dialer

[Android's UI](http://www.naldotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/private-number-android.jpg) that i want to replace with my own. So is it possible to replace and yes, then please suggest me some User-Permission to do so

Comment: My caller doesn't look like that, so the answer is obviously, yes. But you need root permission to install a separate Dialer app

Comment: ok, thanks a lot brother but can you tell me how to get root privileges?

Comment: That depends on your phone, and asking for tutorials is off topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303138/how-to-make-my-own-custom-dialer-in-an-android-phone

Comment: thanks for sparing your precious time, but it was not at all the duplicate one as i have already created my UI and i simply want to replace with android's default one :)

Comment: Okay, well do you have an `<intent-filter>` for the ACTION_DIAL Intent? Have you tried going into your device's settings to override the Dialer application's default behavior?

Comment: yes i have, and also i have added NEW_OUTGOIN_CALL intent as well, and i have given permission too, still it was not enough to override. something more is required and that thing i don't know

Comment: You might want to edit your question to actually include the code you have and the research done, rather than just asking if something is possible.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835987/1916449 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856583/1916449 for steps that are necessary

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own UI and user have to dial number from your app it can be done from API 23, check inCallservice

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html