# Android Dialer & Phonebook interception of intents

Tags: java, android

I have two simple questions:

- is it possible in the Android Dialer application to intercept the ACTION_CALL Intent and offer the user the number to be dialed with another application (that is when the user clicks 'Dial' button). I know Dialer is custom app on every ROM so I suppose this is impossible?
- is it possible when the user selects a contact from the Phonebook/Contacts and presses Dial for particular number (maybe predefined with some prefix or suffix), the app to recognize and to complete the dialing with third party app and not the default Dialer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to intercept the intent and let your app show in the dialog prompting the user to continue the call with the default dialer or your own. This might be of help :

[Android dialer application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application)