# Android: overriding dialer application or turning it off

Tags: java, android, service, forceclose, android-permissions

I need to create an application that will replace the default dialer when the phone is ringing. so when someone is calling to me i want to auto answer the call and do some other work but without the user knowing that someone has called.

so bassically what i need is a way to hide the fact someone is calling by stopping the default dialer from opening and hiding the notification for an exsisting conversation(after i answer the call)

the only things i found so far is a way to make an application that will appear on the dialer chooser when calling from contacts, but how can i set my dialer default when someone is calling to me?

i realized that i can actually not use my application as a default dialer, but rather detect a phone call and turn the dialer off. the quetion is how can i do it that way then?
i need not only close the dialer application but the service itself to hide the notification too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application

Comment: http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/simpleDialer.html

Comment: these arent helping me, i need a dialer that will open automatically when the phone is ringing, not when the application is launched manually