# Android: calling a phone number on start of an application

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm new to Android, so 
is there a way to automatically call a number (or at least put it in the phone's dialer) when an app is opened? (the app needs no GUI, it just needs to call when opened)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4816772/2761813) helps, just tried a fast google search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To make a call,**

```
private void performDial(String numberString) {
if (!numberString.equals("")) {
   Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + numberString);
   Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
   startActivity(dial);
}
```

}

**Add this permission into manifest.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993055/make-a-call-in-android/26993080#26993080)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside onCreate() of activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent)
```

Also give calling permission inside android manifest file.
Permission :

Comment: Thanks! <3 that was REALLY fast!

Comment: You can upvote the answers which suite your question.