# Can we set the location of android keyboad? if yes how?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in Android. I am creating a calling app, where I am using android keyboard. but at the bottom I want "Dial" Button which should show even after the keyboard is appear. Currently I created a screen where all working is fine but when keyboard appears the "Dial" button is get hidden. This is the scenario, please suggest me, Can we set the location of android keyboard or What else I can do.? Please suggest me how can I do this.
Thanks in advance.
The Wireframe for screen is like below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this link Might solve your problem.

[Android_Dialer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application)