# Creating custom android dialer

Tags: android, android-intent, telephony, phone-call, android-dialer

I am working on the new phone app for Android. Obviously it needs to make and receive phone calls.

My first problem is how to place a phone call from the app without invoking System default dialer. Making calls using Intent is very easy. However when I try to place a call without using Intent then that's entirely different ball of wax.

It seems that I need to use android.telephony but I can't find any good resources that could tell me where to start. Simple tutorial would be nice.

If you could point me to a resource that would help me that will be really appreciated.

Comment: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/simple-dialer-application/

Comment: Example is using Intent to pass phone number to the existing Dialer. That is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: Here you can find a custom dialer : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/PadLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an app that responds to `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`. In the `AndroidManifest.xml` you need to add the following to that Activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can read more in:

> [Android dialer application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5029183/3653989)

Comment: @svager you got some advance?

Answer (score 1):

From Android 10 onwards the only way to handle phone calls is by using the `InCallService` APIs. I have made a basic dialer app that explains basics of how to handle calls as a default dialer app. https://github.com/adnan-creator/java-custom-dialer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind adding the relevant source code from the link you posted to it?

Comment: @PatrickKlein It's a whole app, there isn't any particular code that would specifically be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i faced same problem
couldn't ask default dialer in phone os >= Q android
check my asnwer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094871/15072590

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).