# Is it possible to call ACTION_CALL on button But call should be done in background

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjHmJ.png)Is it possible to call ACTION_CALL on button But call should be done in background
In this when we click on button then call should be done in background and we dont want to see number we can see on button and automatically call will be go to static number . When I use this code then this screen wil be appear and i am not want to appear this screen.

Comment: Call in background? What do you mean?? Calling without calling interface?

Comment: yes when i click on button then we can see only button not other calling interface

Answer (score 1):

It would not be possible as that would intrude privacy.

If you were routing the call through non mobile network (say you are building an Hangouts app) then there are some means by capturing the URI pattern. But if you are wanting to use the Phone's antenna then it is not possible.

This blog describes your interests
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html

However if you are looking to build a custom dialer then below thread will be of some help.
[Android dialer application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application)

You could may be build a dialer with your application's requirement embedded.