# Android : How to integrate dialer in app like true caller

Tags: android, android-dialer

I would want to integrate dialer in my application like one in True Caller.
Is there any 3rd party library or android provide any interface for that.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So you need your own dialer layout? Why? You can link a phone number to send an Intent to the built in dialer app

Answer (score 2):

If you want your own Dialer in your application then for that you will need to create your custom UI and have to add some `intent-filter`, `Permission` in `Manifest` file. Also have to respond on `Intent.ACTION_CALL`.
the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application) by [zirael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611319/zirael) will guide you.