# How to include my phone call application on the 'open with' list?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

I'm developing a phone call application similar to the native stock Android phone call application. It's completed and fully operational. I would like it that if a phone number link is pressed that it shows my app in the "To open with" list along side with the native app.

I've read about how a deep link can me made for a url and other files, but I haven't found anything related to dialing. I've tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
           <intent-filter
                android:label="@string/app_name">

                <data android:scheme="myapp"
                    android:mimeType="text/plain"/>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!

Started searching how others made their dialer applications work and found this post [Android dialer application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application).

This last part of the marked answer is what made it work.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
 </intent-filter>
```