# Run USSD Code in Android without using " Intent.ACTION_CALL"

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

I am creating a App in Android, which required run USSD Code in background.
without send my application in background,

Whenever I am using  Intent.ACTION_CALL to run USSD

```
   String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
   String ussd = "*123" + encodedHash;
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd));
   startActivity(intent);
```

it send my application in background, and open dialer Interface on my application.

So it is possible to run USSD code without open Dialer Interface in front.

Thanks In advance .

Answer (score 2):

It's a kind of complex...
You need to override the default dialer. 
Like the way Skype does.
[How to include my application as a dialing option when calling from the addressbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293864/how-to-include-my-application-as-a-dialing-option-when-calling-from-the-addressb)

[Dial Number Without Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811680/dial-number-without-prompt)

Comment: Thanks, I want to use some fixed code, So i think i need not dialing option.