# Delphi XE8 FMX Android and USSD codes

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, ussd

I have tried to use the phonedialer to submit and receive USSD codes using Delphi XE8 FMX
Not sure if that was the right way to go about it since it still shows the dialer and results via the phone and not in my app.
Has anybody had any success running and showing USSD codes in delphi app for Android? Am I on the right track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run USSD codes in Android devices but you would be unable to parse the result in your application (This is not related to Delphi, same problem also on Java). This feature might be added to the Android SDK in the future but for now, you would have to look for an alternative.

[Run USSD Code in Android without using " Intent.ACTION_CALL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489143/run-ussd-code-in-android-without-using-intent-action-call)