# launching my app when dialing a number

Tags: android

I want to show my app as a option when dialing a number - new or contact. I have followed [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499550/using-android-dialer-in-3rd-party-app). I have an app with a single activity. Here is the manifest file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SomeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILIGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally it worked. I misspelled the word 'PRIVILEGED' as PRIVILIGED