# how to get dialed mobile number in my application?

Tags: android, phone-number, phone-call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [launching my app when dialing a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310372/launching-my-app-when-dialing-a-number)

I would like to get the mobile number from dialer which has dialed by user in my android application.I have implemented an application as follows:

```
 ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:")));

        }
    });
```

from the above code i can open dialer app.If user enter a mobile number and click for call then i would like to get which number he has typed.
please any body help on it...

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this thread - the "duplicate" is not discussing at all the fetching of the phone number. Furthermore the answer there is with a lot lower value. If you wish to close a thread, close the other one.

Comment: I am also trying something like this. But i want to get the number before the call is made as soon as something is dialed in the dialer app. Can any body help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution as following code

```
public class OutGoingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) 
   {
         // get phone number from bundle
         String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(OutGoingCall.INTENT_PHONE_NUMBER);

   }
}
```

Comment: Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneno));

Comment: you can do like this also Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+pnmu));
    context.startActivity(callIntent); for sending number through variable

Answer (score 9):

You can use BroadcastReceiverto do that :

Register a BroadcastReceiver like this in Manifest file:

```
    <!-- DIAL Receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="receivers.DialBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

You need Permission for NEW_OUTGOING_CALL :

```
<!-- OUTGOING CALL PERMISSION-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Eventually you can Receive the broadcast and retrieve the dialed number like this:

```
public class DialBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.v("DileBroadCastReceiver","In onReceive()");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
         String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

         Log.v("DialBroadcast Receiver","Number is: "+number);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS is banned (January 2019) since the app is not the default phone calls handler