# get number, which customer dialed from standard dialpad

Tags: android

i try catch a call from standard dialpad using that code:

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
   </intent-filter>


</activity>
```

Everything fine, when user dial from standard phone dialpad, my app opened.
But i don't find solution, how i can get a phone number, which user was dialed. That code inside PhonePadActivity activity onCreate block:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
Toast.makeText(this, "Call was made to-->>" + number, 5000).show();
```

gives me a null finally :(

tried to using brodacast receiver:

in manifest:

> ```
>     <receiver
>         android:exported="true"
>         android:name="com.myapps.android.DialBroadcastReceiver" >
>         <intent-filter >
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </receiver>
>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
> ```

this is class DialBroadcastReceiver:

```
package com.myapps.android;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class DialBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String THIS_FILE = "PhonePadActivity";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(THIS_FILE,"In onReceive()");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
             String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

             Log.e(THIS_FILE,"Number is: "+number);

        }
    }

}
```

but logs nod fired, when user press dial

Comment: Add a bit more code - do you use `BroadcastReceiver` or what? Also look into this thread, hopefully it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909153/how-to-get-dialed-mobile-number-in-my-application

Comment: @Boris Strandjev see edited question - i don't using broadcast receiver currently :(

Comment: @BorisStrandjev please look to edited question

Comment: The edits just show copy-pastes from the post I linked to. Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev please look to updates, there is exact code, which i'm using....

Comment: Do you log: `Log.e(THIS_FILE,"In onReceive()");`. Do you have the following permission in the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />`?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev yes, permissions is there and log not seen inside log cat...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21895/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-user170317)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the number with incorrect code. Replace:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
Toast.makeText(this, "Call was made to-->>" + number, 5000).show();
```

With:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData(); 
if (data != null && ("tel".equals(data.getScheme()))) { 
    String number = PhoneNumberUtils.getNumberFromIntent(getIntent(), this); 
    if (number != null) { 
      Toast.makeText(this, "Call was made to-->>" + number, 5000).show();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

In Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
    <data android:scheme="tel"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In Activity:

```
String inputURI = this.getIntent().getDataString();
if (inputURI != null) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(inputURI));
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("tel")) {
        String calledNumber = uri.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add `<intent-filter android:priority="9999">` to the intent-filter declaration in the manifest, to make sure you're first in line
- Remove the `com.myapps.android`-part from the `android:name` property of the receiver declaration in the manifest (i.e. it should be: `android:name=".DialBroadcastReceiver"`)

Comment: hi. i can't verify if priority working well, bcs i'm in list first as my app started from C ;) but thnx for advanced topic

Answer (score 0):

Register a `BroadcastReceiver` like this in `Manifest` file:

```
<!-- DIAL Receiver -->
<receiver
    android:exported="true"
    android:name="receivers.DialBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You need Permission for `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` :

Eventually you can Receive the broadcast and retrieve the dialed number like this:

```
public class DialBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.v("DileBroadCastReceiver","In onReceive()");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
      String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
      Log.v("DialBroadcast Receiver","Number is: "+number);
    }
  }
}
```