# Java Android: Display a message from Android phone when a user types a particular word from the keyboard

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a way I can pop a Toast when ever a user types a particular number from the keyboard eg 999 in the android phone. I have made a research regarding this but what am seeing is to make a toast at interval or launch an app on dialing a number. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get dialed mobile number in my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909153/how-to-get-dialed-mobile-number-in-my-application)

Comment: Before asking question,Please search

Comment: There are two many answers already available for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can make a toast , when the user enters a numeric value equal to 999 , this will throw a toast.The toast can be thrown at a button click, the button click method(onButtonClick()).

```
public void onButtonClick(View View) { 
final EditText numberText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberInputEditBox); 
if (numberText.equals(999)) { 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Have Entered The Number 999!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your edit text add an aftertextchangelistener using addTextChangeListener() method. And if the text input equals "999" you can show your toast message.