# Make Android app appear in list of default applications?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have the source code of a 'Phone' app that dials a number and makes a call. How do I make it visible in a list of available applications when a person chooses any 'Phone' shortcut?

I have tried implementing the action intent filters `android.intent.action.CALL` and `android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED` but it only shows my app in the list AFTER I dial a number. In other words, my app gets classified as a Dialer rather than a Phone.

Is there any specific `BroadcastReceiver` that I need to implement? How do I do that?

Comment: WOW it worked. Does exactly what I hoped for. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well since my comment was what the OP asked for, i replicate it here.

"have you tried CALL_BUTTON (as an intent filter in your manifest) ?"

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3500861/1101070) answer is probably what you're looking for. So essentially you'll first need to setup an intent filter on the activity that's going to make the call (in `AndroidManifest.xml`):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

This should give your user the option to use your app when placing calls, similarly to how [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) works.

Comment: I have already done that. However, doing so shows my app in the list of Dialer apps, not phone apps. My app only contains a set of number buttons and a textview. The user enters the number and clicks the Call button, which then fires an ACTION_CALL intent to call that particular number.. If I add a filter for android.intent.action.CALL then when I press the Call button in my app, a list appears with the stock Dialer AND my app in it..