# Opening/Displaying the default dialer in app (actually using the dialer not passing data to it)?

Tags: android, mobile, android-intent, telephony

I've looked at a few posts here [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499550/using-android-dialer-in-3rd-party-app) but this doesn't seem to do what I intend (unless I'm just doing it wrong.) The other posts I see are either about replacing the dialer with a custom dialer or passing an input to the dialer.

I don't want to replace the dialer and I don't want to pass the data where the user inputs a number and then sends it to the dialer.

I would just like to bring in the default dialer inside the app. Example:

1) The user opens the app, they see their default dialer but with a different heading (just so they know they're inside my app). They enter the number, press call it calls the number.

2) If the user presses their call button outside of the app, they just do the normal dialer without my app. So the user never uses my app in (2).

I think that's pretty clear but if not just let me know. Since I can't seem to find any tutorials or posts about doing this online, it leads me to wonder if this is against a policy? Or perhaps a concern the users will be confused as to what they're doing? I think with a different heading they can know if they are using my app or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would just like to bring in the default dialer inside the app

Sorry, but that is not possible.

> it leads me to wonder if this is against a policy?

If by "against policy" you mean "not possible from a technical standpoint", then yes, it is against policy. You cannot embed the UI from another process in yours, by and large. This is not unique to the dialer, or to your app.

Comment: So I cannot import another process either? So by what you're saying the only way is to create a custom dialer and pass the uri to ACTION_DIAL? What about apps like Skype, where it makes calls from the default dialer? Thanks for your answer, btw. I figured this had to be the case since I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: @RKS: "So I cannot import another process either?" -- I have no idea what that sentence means to you, sorry. "So by what you're saying the only way is to create a custom dialer and pass the uri to ACTION_DIAL?" -- if you want a dialer in your UI, design it yourself, then use `ACTION_DIAL` or `ACTION_CALL` to place the phone call. "What about apps like Skype, where it makes calls from the default dialer?" -- AFAICT that is irrelevant to the question at hand, where you want the default dialer to be embedded in your own app.